# Entity Frmwk pb: search for 'added' entities in current context

Tags: entity-framework, constraints, guid

I'm using guids as PK for my entities.
As EF doesn't support the newid() SQL statement, I force a **Guid.NewGuid()** in my creation methods.

Here is my problem :
I've a table with a clustered unique constraint (2 strings, not PK).

I'm running some code in **the same** EF context which perfoms operations and adds/links entities, etc.

**Is it possible to search for an entity in 'Added' state in my context ?** ; that is to say which is in my context, but not yet inserted in my DB.

To avoid the raising of the SQL unique constraint, I have to know if the entity is already 'queued' in the context, and to re-use it instead of creating a new Guid (... and a different entity! :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this post saved me :) :

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926110522/http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/07/23/retrieving-added-entities-from-the-objectstatemanager-to-avoid-duplication.aspx)

```
var stateEntries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EtityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged);  
    var roleEntityEntries = stateEntries.Select(s => s.Entity).OfType<Role>();  
    roleEntity = roleEntityEntries.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleName.Trim().ToLower() == roleName.Trim().ToLower());  
    if (roleEntity == null)  
    {  
        return new Role { RoleName = roleName };  
    }
```